# Xgboost multiclass predicton with linear booster

Tags: r, xgboost

Does it make sense to use a linear booster to predict a categorical outcome?
I thought it could work like multinomial logistic regression.

An example in R is as follows,

```
y <- c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2)        # target variable with numeric encoding
x1 <- c(1, 3, 5, 3, 5, 7)
x2 <- rnorm(n = 6, sd = 1) + x1
df <- data.matrix(data.frame(x1, x2, y))

xgb <- xgboost(data = df[, c("x1", "x2")], label = df[, "y"],
           params = list(booster = "gblinear", objective = "multi:softmax", 
           num_class = 3),
           save_period = NULL, nrounds = 1)

xgb.importance(model = xgb)
```

I don't get an error but the importance has 6 features instead of the expected 2.  Is there any interpretation of the 6 importances in terms of the 2 input variables?  Or does this not make any sense and only `gbtree` is sensible? 
Thanks

Comment: To add to above, The fact there are 6 importances is related to there being 3 classes in the target. If there are 4 classes then there are 8 importances.  In the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/xgboost.pdf) the _Weight_ of each feature importance is described as "percentage representing the relative number of times a feature have been taken into
trees." which obviously ignores the fact that xgb.importance can be applied to gblinear, as also specified in the docs.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2331) for useful comments